# fullcalendar always renders Week view starting from 6am, need other time

Tags: fullcalendar

when first rendered on page (in Week view), FullCalendar window always starts at 6am.

http://prnt.sc/e3yi17

Is there an option that changes this behaviour so that the default window position is at some other time, say 10am? I just don't have tasks starting at 6am so I don't want to scroll down every time a page opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [scrollTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/scrollTime/) property:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: "agendaWeek",
  scrollTime: "15:00:00"
});
```

Try [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5z9w8jgb/).